# Where can I find these textured cast concrete blocks?

Tags: walls, concrete-block

I am trying to match up some old blocks but ain't having much luck.
Would anybody know the name or style of the block?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find them offered online either. The quality/style has changed quite a bit since those were made, and I think they've been outmoded.

I found something similar: http://www.uticacast.com/Veneer.htm

[image]